# How to allow a standard user run a specific application without admin password?

Tags: windows-10, uac, standard-user

I made a standard account for a friend and we downloaded an application. However when opening this application, it asks to run as administrator and asks for the admin password. Is there a way I can disable it just for that application on the standard account? I thought of running this application as a startup program in task manager or somehow giving the program administrator rights when the PC launches. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the application has a manifest file to adjust user permissions, you can do that. Not many apps have this facility.

Otherwise, if you can have it run at Windows Log in, you can set it up in Task Scheduler to run at log in, and set elevated permission and your admin credentials for the app. This is found in the General Tab of the Task Schedule setup.